# Form field validation failure HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am using a HTML5 form field [in chrome], in a previous question I asked how to update one with a time reference, some reason my function wasn't working or being called as expected but I got it fixed, since that was sorted another problem cropped up and that is one where the form is submitted and the field validation for the p_time field causes a notice to pop up, for example if the time was 12:53:22 and I hit submit, up pops a validation notice from the field to say that the nearest acceptable input it 12:53 or 12:54.

This is no good to me, I need hours, minutes and seconds as the time reference, any suggestions as to why

```
<input name="p_time" type="time" value="<?php echo date("H:i:s");?>" />
```

when a javascript updates the field with a string 00:00:00 type, it results in a validation error.

The update script is something like:

```
time = {
    target:document.forms[0].p_time,
    tick:function(){
        time.target.value = new Date().toUTCString().slice(17,25);
    },
    auto:setInterval("time.tick()",1000)
}
```

where it updates the p_time input every second but results in a validation error on submit of the form.

Comment: Regarding: `new Date().toUTCString().slice(17,25)`. The [*toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.42) method is implementation dependant (i.e. there is no requirement for it to fit any specific format) so expect unexpected results.

Comment: Where is the code that validates the value of the *p_time* input?

Comment: The HTML5 validates the date, no additional code needed, the input either needs to update automatically per second or it remains static, the problem is the seconds that are set are not being accepted by HTML5 and HTML5 suggests a time either side in whole minutes. As the value is being set by a script, no actual validation code in the traditional sense is needed if the browser supports HTML5, if it doesn't, then a fall back is needed, however, HTML5 is supported by most browsers.